# What will make insertion method in this BST code work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, binary-search-tree

the class seems to be working well except the insertion method. All the print statement methods are working. I want to insert a node into the tree but once I call, `r.insertion(7,3)`, it does not work and says there is no "attribute to key". How can I fix this binary search tree?

```py
class BinarySearchTree:
    def __init__(self,rootObj):
        self.key = rootObj
        self.leftChild = None
        self.rightChild = None

    def insertLeft(self,newNode):
        if self.leftChild == None:
            self.leftChild = BinarySearchTree(newNode)
        else:
            t = BinarySearchTree(newNode)
            t.leftChild = self.leftChild
            self.leftChild = t

    def insertRight(self,newNode):
        if self.rightChild == None:
            self.rightChild = BinarySearchTree(newNode)
        else:
            t = BinarySearchTree(newNode)
            t.rightChild = self.rightChild
            self.rightChild = t
            
    def insertion(self,root, num):
    
        if root == None:
            return Node(num)
        #check if less than
        
        if num < root.key:
            root.left = insertion(self, root.left, num)
            
        elif num >= root.key:
            root.right = insertion(self, root.right, num)
            
        return root


    def getRightChild(self):
        return self.rightChild

    def getLeftChild(self):
        return self.leftChild

    def setRootVal(self,obj):
        self.key = obj

    def getRootVal(self):
        return self.key


r = BinarySearchTree(7)
print(r.getRootVal())
print(r.getLeftChild())
r.insertLeft(4)
print(r.getLeftChild())
print(r.getLeftChild().getRootVal())
r.insertRight(9)
print(r.getRightChild())
print(r.getRightChild().getRootVal())
r.getRightChild().setRootVal('hello')
print(r.getRightChild().getRootVal())
print(r.insertion(7,3))
```

Thank you.

Comment: In `r.insertion(7,3)` you are passing `7` as integer value. Integer value does not have any attribute called `key`. But in `insertion` method you are treating first parameter as a `Node` object. So, you need to pass `Node` object in `insertion` method.

Answer (score 0):

Accoding to your function definiton, `def insertion(self,root, num)` takes 2 main parameters:

1. `root`: which has to be an object of class `BinarySearchTree` according to your implementation
2. `num`, which will be an `int`

When you call `r.insertion(7,3)`, the `num` gets an int; however, the `root` parameter is also getting an `int`, which is incorrect (and that's the reason behind the error). If you want insertion in `r`, you'll have to call it using `r.insertion(r, 3)`, since `r` is the rootnode of the BST where you want to insert the value.

Comment: Which begs the question, why is there both `self` and `root`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice agreed, according to OP's implementation it's better to move the ```insertion()``` method outside the class

Comment: Or the class design needs to be modified to hide implementation details that should not be part of the public API.

Comment: It would be better (I guess) if there was a separate ```Node``` class